# I was unable to show route direction over tiled map

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins, direction

Actually have two questions.
1) can I use tiled map for showing the direction? If ans is yes! Then 2nd question is
2) Am on a project where my client is looking for a GPS navigation like facility in his word press website! Where I already archive the tracking facility over tiled map without start and end route direction. Map & its associated code came from leaflet eg. So now I want the route direction on that Same map instead of a separate map!
How do I do or how do I achive that?

I will be glad if some one help in this regards. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you done so far? please provide minimal, complete, verifiable code. If you encountered errors, you may also include the error logs. For the meantime, check [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), this service can return multi-part directions using series of waypoint.